# XSLT 2.0: Limit the ancestor axes to a certain element/s level up the document tree

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I'm seeing a quite odd behaviour, when trying to limit the results given by applying ancestor::* to an element I always get an extra ancestor although is expressly excluded by the predicate.

Here the code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <level_a> 
    <level_b> 
      <level_c> 
        <level_d> 
          <level_e/> 
        </level_d> 
      </level_c> 
    </level_b> 
  </level_a>
  <level_b> 
    <level_c> 
      <level_d> 
        <level_d> 
          <level_e/> 
        </level_d> 
      </level_d> 
    </level_c> 
  </level_b>
</root>
```

XPath:

```
(//level_d[not(level_d)])[last()]/ancestor::*[level_c|level_b]
```

so basically I'm selecting the **level_d** elements that doesn't have another **level_d** element nested, getting the last one of them and trying to get all the ancestors up to element **level_b**. 
But the result I'm seeing using Altova XMLSpy 2011 is:

- level_a
- level_b

I don't quite understand why I'm getting that result and how can I improve my xpath to limit effectively the ancestors up to **level_b** (i.e. level_c and level_b).

Any hint is greatly appreciated!
Regards
Vlax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `ancestor::*[level_c|level_b]` selects all elements on the ancestor axis that have a `level_c` or `level_b` child.

You might want `(//level_d[not(level_d)])[last()]/ancestor::*[self::level_c|self::level_b]`.

Or with your textual description "to limit effectively the ancestors to level_b" you simply want `(//level_d[not(level_d)])[last()]/ancestor::level_b`.

Comment: Thanks! the first suggestion was exactly what I was looking for. I will correct the description of what I'm trying to achieve because it's not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you get right result because clause `ancestor::*[level_c|level_b]` I read as "all ancestors containing element level_b or level_c". So, level_b is ok because it contains level_c and level_a is ok too because it contains level_b.

So if I change your XPath into `(//level_d[not(level_d)])[last()]/ancestor::*[level_c]` it results into level_b only.

Probably it is not exactly what you asking for but I'm not sure if I understand well the purpose of your XPath :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was in the direction. @Martin go it right.